# .NET 6.0 Blazor Server app: WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:60908/BlazorApp1/' failed

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022

When I create a new, clean Blazor .NET 6.0 app and start it (using Visual Studio 2022), I see the following error in the browser console:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:60908/BlazorApp3/' failed: (aspnetcore-browser-refresh.js:234)
```

[image: Error in browser console]

Does anyone else have this and any idea if this is a VS2022 bug and how to fix it?

Comment: Have you enabled Web Socket support in IIS?

Comment: Thank you, I tried adding UseWebsockets() in program.cs, but I have the same error in the browser console when using either IIS or Kestrel. Looks like this bug https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/34975 is still not resolved. Or else I am missing something??

Comment: go to Turn Windows Features on and off > Internet Information Services > World Wide Web Services > App Development Features > Enable WebSocket Protocol. Does this work?

Comment: Switching off "Enable Hot Reload and Edit and Continue when debugging" seemed to resolve this issue for me. However, I feel that is probably using a hammer to crack a nut. As others have suggested, it could be related to IIS Express/Kestrel Web Sockets.

Comment: I tried your suggestions (enabled Web Sockets in IIS) but it does not work. The error still appears (same when starting it using Kestrel).
I think it's a bug related Hot Reload / Edit & Continue, I hope it will be fixed in a future update of VS2022... I have reported this to Microsoft through the Visual Studio feedback pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same issue has been discussed here https://developercommunity2.visualstudio.com/t/WebSocket-connection-to-wss:-fail/1670519?q=ERR_CONNECTION_RESET&ftype=problem&space=8&stateGroup=active&sort=newest and the fix is available with VS 17.2 Preview 2.1

Answer (score 6):

I had exactly the same issue after installing Visual Studio 2022. I tried to "Enable WebSocket Protocol" but that didn't work. However, the fix for me was to change [Script Debugging to "Enabled"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TSJ3C.png).

Hopefully, this can help you too.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30941780)

Comment: Well, enabling script debugging did help me, although I can still see the `WebSocket failed to connect.` error. I guess that with debugging enabled, Visual Studio falls back to some other means of communication to accomplish hot reload.